# Parsing XML - recovering images

Tags: image, simplexml, mime, store

Can anyone please explain to me how to generate an image from a remote server using simplexml and store it in a temporary image file or point me to a tutorial that would shed some light on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary data is typically stored in XML using base64 encoding. You would run a base64 decode function over the data to get the image data.

Comment: So... OK... would I have to store the temporary image in a database or something? Sorry I just usually never have to do this kind of thing...